# How to create an effecient portable timer in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, linux

For a school project I need to (re)create a fully functional multi-player version of R-Type without the use of the following external libraries:

- Boost
- SFML/SDL
- Qt
- Use of C++11 not allowed

Moreover, this game must be fully portable between Fedora(Linux) and Windows. I am in charge of the server so the use of any graphic libraries is strictly prohibited.

In order to create a correct game loop I need a correct Timer class, similar as those found in the SDL which implements GetTicks() or GetElapsedTime() methods. But I asked myself what would be the best way to create such a Class, so far this is how I would start:

- Creating a threaded-class using pthread(which is portable)
- Using the functions time() and difftime() in a loop to determine how much time was elapsed since the last tick.

Knowing that this class will be used by dozens of instances playing at the same time, should I use the Singleton Design Pattern? Will this methods be accurate?

**EDIT:** Changed the explanation of my question to fit more my needs and to be more accurate on what I am allowed to use or not.

Comment: Er, pthreads is **not** part of C++.

Comment: If you can't use external libraries, you'll have no way of doing graphics either. So basically, your requirements contradict themselves.

Comment: Can you use C++11? Then you could use the new chrono stuff. Also, I wonder how you create your graphics, since C++ doesn't come with any graphics library... so are you maybe allowed to use some libraries that you forgot to tell us?

Comment: If it's for school, and C++11 isn't specified as a "NO" on the assignment, then just use it. C++11 *is* valid C++. Your professor cannot grade you down for it.

Comment: @jalf: I am in charge of the core of the game(basically this is going to be a multi-player version of r-type), so I won't need the graphics right now.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I am not allowed to use the C++11 version unfortunately

Comment: @Ephismen: with these requirements this is simply not doable: you can't get high-resolution timers and you can't access the network in C++ without external libraries.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: well I am allowed to create abstraction in order to use Linux or Windows Threads or Sockets, but that is all. No Boost, no SDL, no SFML, no Qt. At least for the server.

Comment: You should write that in your question, so people can help you with that

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Changed my question and pardon me not being accurate on my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not an easy way to do what you're thinking.  Luckily, there are easy ways to do what you want.

First: `Using the functions time() and difftime() in a loop to determine how much time was elapsed` That's a terrible idea.  That will use 100% of one of your CPUs and thus slow your program to a crawl.  If you want to wait a specific amount of time (a "tick" of 1/60 of a second, or 1/10 of a second), then just wait.  Don't spin a thread.

header:

```
long long get_time();
long long get_freq();
void wait_for(long long nanoseconds);
```

cpp:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER //windows compiler for windows machines
long long get_time() {
    LARGE_INTEGER r;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(r);
    return r.QuadPart;
}
long long get_freq() {
    LARGE_INTEGER r;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(r);
    return r.QuadPart;
}
void wait_for(long long nanoseconds)
{
    Sleep(nanoseconds / 1000000);
}
#endif
#ifdef __GNUC__ //linux compiler for linux machines
long long get_time() {
    timespec r
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &r);
    return long long(r.seconds)*1000000000 + r.nanoseconds;
}
long long get_freq() {
    timespec r
    clock_getres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &r);
    return r.nanoseconds;
}
void wait_for(long long nanoseconds)
{
    timespec r = {nanoseconds/1000000000, nanoseconds%1000000000};
    nanosleep(&r, NULL);
}
#endif
```

None of this is perfect (especially since I don't code for linux), but this is the general concept whenever you have to deal with the OS (since it isn't in the standard and you cant use libraries).  The Windows and GCC implementations can be in separate files if you like

Comment: Thank you for this code sample. It will surely help me understanding the logic behind a Timerclass. I now relize how heavy would have been my timer in the way I had planned to do it. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Given the spec pthreads are out, not going to run on windows, not included in the standard.

If you can use C++11 you can use std::chrono for the timer this is a high precision timer, with a fairly intuitive interface. It has basically been lifted from boost (as has thread), so most of the documentation for boost translate to std::chrono.
(or for low precision just use the C time library) and for threads you can use std::thread.

N.B. these elements of the standard library and you just create test on your platforms to make sure the stdlib you are using supports them (you will need to enable c++11 - usually --std=c++0x)

I know for sure that gcc 4.6 has the majority of thread and chrono in and seems to be stable.

Comment: Those things are, unfortunately, not timers, they put your process to sleep. Ideally, epoll, kqueue and HR timers should be used on different platforms, but those are not in C++ standard... :(

Comment: There is a Windows version of pthread (I used it few years ago in a cross-platform project): http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32

Comment: kol: again std::thread will be the future proof version, and failing that boost::thread is preferential because it is so close to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a wrapper around `gettimeofday` for Linux which returns the number of microseconds since the Epoch, and `GetTickCount` for Windows which returns the number of milliseconds since the system was started.

You can also use [clock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on Windows which will return seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC (yes, wall-clock time not CPU time) since the process started.

Comment: No, you need to use the Windows High Performance Timer for high-resolution timing on Windows.

Comment: Neither of those are in C++ standaed. One is POSIX, another one is nothing :)

Comment: @DeadMG I think it would depend on the resolution he's looking for. I think these would be sufficient for his needs. I don't believe there are any portable timers so we're stuck with POSIX and broken Windows functions.

Answer (score 0):

To get a wall time you could use `QueryPerformanceCounter` on Windows and `clock_gettime()` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` on POSIX systems (`CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` Linux 2.6.28+).